# If there is an error, how can I exit from SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a SSIS package that has a Sequence Container with serveral Data Flow Tasks in it. If any Data Flow in the Sequence Container incurs an error, I want the package to exit running rather than hanging out there. How can I make it happen?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Generally this happens automatically, unless you've done something to prevent it.

Comment: I Use sql server agent for running ssis packages .
After running package, sometimes job execution failed and still hang out there.
I want to know if I need to use event handler or Constraint on error to exit the running

Comment: Maybe you need to edit the job instead of the package.  What do you have in the advanced properties of the job step for "On Failure Action"?

Comment: Hi Tab, "Send notification" is in the advanced properties of the job step for "On Failure Action"

Comment: Change it to "quit reporting failure"

Comment: Hi Tab,Can I have option to choose both, "quit reporting failare" and "send Notification"

Comment: Not in the "On Failure Action".    You could use the package to send a notification in the OnError event handler.   Or use the Notifications tab on the Job, instead of in the individual step.

Comment: Do you know how a SSIS package can throw an error to an agent job in order to trigger "On Failure Action"?

Comment: Make sure that the task in the package has "FailPackageOnFailure" set to true.

Comment: Hi Tab, Thank you for your answer! I set up each task in the package "FailPackageOnFailure"

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your steps and containers all have `MaximumErrorCount` setting to at least 1.

[image: Properties]